# WindowFrame setting in config.lua missing in Kobold2D 2.X

Tags: lua, kobold2d

I am wondering where has the WindowFrame setting in the config.lua file gone in Kobold2D 2.X? Is there another way to set the window resolution under OS X?

For the moment I managed to set the window size by modifying the Kobold2D sources, but I am wondering if I am missing a new easy way to to that without having to modify the library myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the WindowFrame setting. I removed that because it's redundant and overrides the same settings in MainMenu.xib:

[image]

The initial position in the xib is set to Auto (center). That's something you couldn't do with the config.lua, it forced the window to be at an absolute position regardless of the actual screen resolution.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't know of the existence of such xib file :) Perhaps another thing to mention in the next edition of your Cocos2D book.